# The meaning of a kind of property definition in Typescript interface

Tags: typescript

I encountered a interface definition, like the following one:

```
interface config {
    align?: 'left' | 'center' | 'right';
}
```

What's the meaning of property definition? Where can I find the explanation about it online?
Does it mean I can only assign `left`/`center`/`right` to the property `assign`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly, that is how it works. Go to [Advanced Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) and scroll down to "String Literal Types"

It is basically a simplified enum type that only allows certain string values, and is very useful to annotate libraries which accept behavior through "magic strings".

Quoting the article:

> String literal types allow you to specify the exact value a string
>   must have. In practice string literal types combine nicely with union
>   types, type guards, and type aliases. You can use these features
>   together to get enum-like behavior with strings.

```
type Easing = "ease-in" | "ease-out" | "ease-in-out";
class UIElement {
    animate(dx: number, dy: number, easing: Easing) {
        if (easing === "ease-in") {
            // ...
        }
        else if (easing === "ease-out") {
        }
        else if (easing === "ease-in-out") {
        }
        else {
            // error! should not pass null or undefined.
        }
    }
}

let button = new UIElement();
button.animate(0, 0, "ease-in");
button.animate(0, 0, "uneasy"); // error: "uneasy" is not allowed here
```

Answer (score 0):

That's correct. It means that you are limiting the `align` property to be one of those three values, effectively making it work like an enum.

```
interface config {
    align?: 'left' | 'center' | 'right';
}

// this is valid
const a: config = {
    align:'left'
}

// this is not
const b: config = {
    align:'down'
}
```